# Simulate javascript to choose from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, jquery-trigger

I am trying to simulate a javascript to choose from the dropdown list below. I am trying this code here but its not working.

```js
$('select[name="srctype"]').val(2).trigger('change');
```

Am i doing something wrong here? Is my javascript messed up for this layout of code below?

I am trying to choose `value="single"`

```
<select name="srctype" class="formselect" onchange="typesel_change()">
    <option value="any" selected="selected">any</option>
    <option value="single">Single host or alias</option>
    <option value="network">Network</option>
    <option value="pptp">PPTP clients</option>
    <option value="pppoe">PPPoE clients</option>
    <option value="l2tp">L2TP clients</option>
    <option value="wan">WAN subnet</option>
    <option value="wanip">WAN address</option>
    <option value="lan">LAN subnet</option>
    <option value="lanip">LAN address</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('select[name="srctype"]').val('single')
```

or

```
$('select[name="srctype"] option:eq(1)').prop('selected',1)
```

As you noted in your comment, this worked for you:

```
(function ($) {
    $('select[name="srctype"]').val('single');
}).call(this, jQuery);
```

Comment: Ah i got an error sayingg `TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of null`

Comment: You're using jQuery syntax so you need to include the jQuery library. Are you?

Comment: Well this is on a website im just trying to make an auto script its already loaded.

Comment: Well, my solution works as you can see from the jsFiddle link I posted. You'll need to figure out if you're loading jQuery.

Comment: Yeah i called jquery i checked still getting this error strangle when i enter it in my browser console. TypeError: Cannot call method 'prop' of null
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "Cannot call method 'prop' of null"
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error

Comment: Well, without more code or a link to your site I'm afraid I can't do much more.

Comment: Yeah its a router im trying to automate a script its strangely not working for this script but others it works totally fine.

Comment: try wrapping it into IIFE

`(function ($) {
    $('select[name="srctype"]').val('single');
}).call(this, jQuery);`

Comment: Im using jquery 1.6.2  but let me try it

Comment: Yes it worked! `(function ($) { $('select[name="srctype"]').val('single'); }).call(this, jQuery);` worked perfectly.

Comment: Can you update the answer to that :) ill check you right now thanks!!

Comment: Good. Yes, you should be sure to wrap your code in a document ready call as you noted in your last comment. I'll update my answer to match.

Comment: @j08691 - Hey sorry I accidentally edited your answer. I thought it would send you for a review. I don't know how to revert. You can revert it back or modify it. Apologies! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
$('.formselect').val('single').trigger('change');
```

In your code you're trying to set a val `2` that doesn't exist. The value you're interested is actually `single` as you mention in your question.

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/eXONuhu/1/

Comment: So i tried your script replacing formselect with srctype and i get this error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of null`

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVal = $('select[name="srctype"] option:eq(1)').attr('value');
$('select[name="srctype"]').val(myVal).trigger('change');
```

**Or an optimized version**

```
var mySelect = $('select[name="srctype"]');
var myVal = $('option:eq(1)', mySelect).attr('value');
mySelect.val(myVal).trigger('change');
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/P6Ayz/1/