# Output multiple values from a single <option> in a drop-down menu (Highslide JS)

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Before I start, I just want to make sure there isn't a
misunderstanding. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245967/can-an-option-in-a-select-tag-carry-multiple-values) is not what I'm looking.

I created two interactive drop-down menus that show different sections according to your selection from their drop-down menu. Content is hidden until selected from drop-down menu lists. Everything works as planned but I'd like to add some enhancements but I don't know how to accomplish them.

[image: Two drop-down menus show their options]
[image]
[image]

Current behavior:

- When an option is selected from either drop-down menu list, the other drop-down menu list goes back to its default blank selection
- When an option is selected from either drop-down menu list, it will show a `<div class="headline">` which contains sub `<div class="headline_box>`'s
- When hovering your cursor over each `<div class="headline_box>`, the background color will change as a visual feedback
- When clicking on any `<div class="headline_box>`, an in-browser pop-up window will show up for more details. I am using [Highslide JS](http://highslide.com/) to accomplish this.

---

[image]

- I have several instances when an option (from "items" drop-down menu) falls into several categories. When the option is selected, it currently shows one category only, as coded. So I'd like to have a single option show all the appropriate categories. Take for instance 'apple', it would fall into "reds", "greens", and "fruits"--my current workaround is having three "apple" options under the items drop-down list but each one has a different value (inside `<select id="item-filter">` )
- When an option is selected from the items drop-down menu; it will highlight the result by using the background color used when the cursor is hovering. This highlight is temporary, after it's been clicked it should go back to a blank background color.

Code:

[View demo here](http://codepen.io/astroXP/pen/BNdxXK)

Individual files: [HTML](http://codepen.io/astroXP/pen/BNdxXK.html), [CSS](http://codepen.io/astroXP/pen/BNdxXK.css), [JS](http://codepen.io/astroXP/pen/BNdxXK.js)

(To view external files such as CSS, JS -- click on "Settings" at top of the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question you could add all the categories, comma separated for example, in the select option. Then use that info to show what you need.

**HTML**

```
        <span>Items: </span><br />
        <select id="item-filter">
            <option value="blank"></option>
            <option value="greens,reds,fruit">Apple</option>
            <option value="greens,vegetable">Asparagus</option>
            <option value="fruit">Banana</option>
            <option value="reds">Car</option>
        </select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    //Reset background color when clicked
    $(".headline_box").click(function(){$(this).css('background-color','initial')});

    //Filtering
    function selectCategory(category) {
        if (category.attr('id') == 'category-filter') {
            $('#item-filter').val('blank');
        }

        else if (category.attr('id') == 'item-filter') {
            $('#category-filter').val('blank');
        }

        //Show results
        $(".category").hide();
        var depts = category.val().split(',');
        $.each(depts,function(index,value){
             $(".category-" + value).show();
        }); 

        //Highlight results
        $(".headline_box").css('background-color','initial');
        var selected_item = category.find("option:selected").text();                         
        $("h4:contains('"+selected_item+"')").parents(".headline_box").css('background-color','#fae6cf');
    }
```

I have forked your [Code Pen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVjqdB).

For your second question, could you explain it better? I don't understand what are you trying to do.

**UPDATE**

For doing what you proposed in the comments try this:

Add this code **AFTER** you have attached the select change function:

```
      //PRESELECTED-OPTIONS
      var preselectedCategory = "";
      var preselectedItem = "Asparagus";

      if(preselectedCategory && preselectedItem )
        alert("System Error: You can only preselect Category OR Items");
      else if(preselectedCategory){
        var select_val = $("#category-filter option").filter(function () { return $(this).html() == preselectedCategory; }).val();
        $("#category-filter").val(select_val).change();
      }
      else if(preselectedItem){
        var select_val = $("#item-filter option").filter(function () { return $(this).html() == preselectedItem; }).val();
        $("#item-filter").val(select_val).change();
      }
```

Take notice of some things:

1. The default value is selected by the option `text` NOT `value`
2. You can´t select a default category AND item, it will trigger an alert.

Here is the updated [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVjqdB)

References:

1. [Trigger change() event when setting <select>'s value with val() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760873/trigger-change-event-when-setting-selects-value-with-val-function)
2. [jquery : How to select an option by its text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744289/jquery-how-to-select-an-option-by-its-text)

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your help. You nailed it perfectly! As for my second question, I added a GIF so you can see what I mean and explained it in other words; I realized how confusing it was written, indeed.

Comment: Now I understand your second question. I will see what can I do and update my answer.

Comment: I think I got it and updated the Code Pen. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Can I have a pre-selected option form either one of the drop-down list menus AND having triggered the `<div class="headline_box>`?

I've tried several solutions [over](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) and  [over](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16749663/966044) and [over](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18664994/966044) but all it does it having the pre-selected option show up except for the  `<div class="headline_box>`

Comment: This is what I've gotten by adding `<option selected id="reds" value="reds">Reds</option>`
http://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ999.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
          <select id="item-filter" multiple>
            <option value="blank"></option>
            <option value="greens">Apple</option>
            <option value="reds">Apple</option>
            <option value="fruit">Apple</option>
            <option value="vegetable">Asparagus</option>
            <option value="greens">Asparagus</option>
            <option value="fruit">Banana</option>
            <option value="reds">Car</option>
          </select>
```

and add following script

```
$('#category-filter').on('change',function(){
  $("#item-filter").val($(this).val());
});
```

[Working CodePen Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJvLpw)